# Training for older employees

Tags: training

It makes sense that a company will spend more money on training young employees.

How can older employees be compensated if they do not need training?

Assume all do a similar job.

Comment: Hi Lucky, I edited your question slightly to make it more on topic here. Hope this doesn't change your intent too much - feel free to [edit] if so!

Answer (score 11):

Train based on skills needed -- not age.

If you have a team with a 30 and 60 year old, it's possible the 60 year old may need training and the 30-year old will not.

Older employees who don't need training hopefully are more compensated due to their experience/etc. If this is not valued by companies then older employees might just be out of luck.

Now companies *will* be less inclined to invest significant training into someone they expect to leave in the near future. This might be because of retirement or new jobs.

Comment: About the 60 year old - if the retirement age is 65 it still gives that person about 5 years of work. I'm not sure how many companies actually expect employees that are 30 to stick around more than 5 years and in some industries that's extremely optimistic.

Comment: @BenjaminGruenbaum perspectives matter, regardless of reality. There is a strong perception that someone who is 60+ will "Retire soon."

Comment: Right, your answer is about what an employer _should_ do (train based on skills and not age) - my comment referred to that, the fact someone is 60 does not usually imply in the tech industry (for example) that they'll retire sooner than a 30 year old will change jobs.

Comment: @enderland: our you can turn it on its head smh say that it's extremely unlikely that the 60 years old is almost guaranteed to stay for the next 5 years. At that ages, it's highly unlikely for them to just switch job, especially if they have families, etc.

Answer (score 11):

AS a 60 year old, I have never viewed training as compensation. I certainly never would consider it instead of pay!

Training is a spearate budget item generally and it goes to whoever needs it that particular year.

It isn't unfair if I didn't get any and it certainly doesn't mean I should get compensated in some other way.

My skills and experience help dictate my salary level and that is where I am compensated for what I know already without further training. It is true I might expect a significant salary bump if I aquired training in a new area that paid more (such as getting data science training since it is a field that is currently hot and pays very well), but I would expect the younger person to get the same kind of bump.

That said, in a tech field where things are always changing and new tools and languages are coming out, anyone at any age might need training. So again I don't see what age has to do with it.

Comment: Training _is_ compensation. If you switch companies after five years, you can expect better pay if you had some good training than someone who started like you five years ago but had no training.

Comment: I thought companies pay you for *skills* you have, not the "training" you may or may not have received... If you have a skill, it doesn't matter how you got it (i.e., whether it was "training" or your own exploration). It only matters that you have it.

Answer (score 0):

> How can older employees be compensated if they do not need training?

An employer doesn't need to compensate people for things they don't need, when others do need them.

In a good company, people's needs are generally met.

Some people (new and old alike) need training. Some people need insurance to cover their family. Some people need pet insurance. Some people need special chairs. Some people need bigger monitors or more powerful computers. Some people need tuition reimbursement. Some people need eye care. Some people need to leave early. Some people need to come in late.

Others don't need any of those.

Company's aren't usually in the business of trying to balance every individual's needs to compensation to everyone else.

Answer (score -1):

"Training" has a deeper meaning than what is sounds.

1. The employee that requires training is allowed to delay the start date (and the completion date) for the project to account for the training time. What's more, the admission that he needs training means that a slow start is acceptable.
2. Some "training" is clearly a benefit in disguise, for example attending conferences in Las Vegas, Orlando or abroad, when the employee is not expected to immediately apply the new knowledge on the job.
3. Some training can be "personal development" type, for example learning a foreign language, some type of coaching, or a college course.
4. The company's commitment means that it values the employee, or the employee has the power to force the company to provide education.

All this leads me to think that

1. An employee that gets education should really appreciate it.
2. An employee that doesn't need education should be compensated.